# What is the best way to represent/design groups and members in a database

Tags: database, database-design

Suppose that Group and Member are two java objects. Each Member occurs only once in a Group, a Group has zero or more Members. The attributes of these two objects are almost the same. A Member, however, inherits its values from the Group that it belongs to. But the values of the member can be overwritten as well.

What is the best way to design this in a database? The only thing I can think of is to have two tables that represent these two objects. But this mean that the member table contains many similar values.

```
Group table
id| attr1  | attr2  |
---------------------
1 | value1 | value2 |


Member table
id| attr1  | attr2  | group_id | attr3 |
----------------------------------------
1 | value1 | value2 | 1        | foo   |
2 | bar    | value2 | 1        | foo   |
```

As you can see the member 1 has "inherited" its values from group 1 and has its own attr3 value `foo`. Member 2 also "inherited" values from group 1 but its attr1 value has been overwritten by `bar`.

Comment: Please review, comment, choose, vote up, etc.

Answer (score 2):

> *What is the best way to design this in a database?*

The best way is to understand the scientific principles, that data and program elements (including objects) are completely different species, and each has quite different methods and rules for analysis, design, and  implementation.  A real man and a real woman make a great marriage, precisely because each is different.  A confused or enmeshed partner makes a disastrous marriage.

Therefore I will address the data requirement in your question, using standards, such that the data is stable *and* easy to extend.  And you are free to build any object from that, either using Standards, such that the objects are stable and easy to extend.  Or not.

Here is the Normalised Relational database that supports your stated requirement.

[**Group vs Member Attribute Data Model**](http://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Student%20Resolutions/mnish%20DM.pdf)

- No Nulls.  No duplicates of anything.  No Update Anomalies.
- In the default case, the Group attributes are each Members attributes.  These defaults should not be stored per Member, that would be massive and unnecessary duplication.
- You need Optional Columns for the Member attributes that, if set, override the default attributes.

  - I have given each attribute separately, allowing each of them to be set independently over time.  If all of them were to be set together, you can merge them into one optional table.
- Relational Keys are provided, which means you will have the highest level of Relational Integrity, power, and speed.  Given the level of your question, you may not appreciate the value of that right now, but you will appreciate it once you start coding.
- That is an IDEF1X data model.  IDEF1X is the Standard for modelling Relational Databases.  Please be advised that every little tick; notch; and mark; the crows foot; the solid vs dashed lines; the square vs round corners; means something very specific and important.  Refer to the [**IDEF1X Notation**](http://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Documentary%20Examples/IDEF1X%20Introduction.pdf).  If you do not understand the Notation, you will not be able to understand or *work* the model.

Of course, a Member should occur just once in each Group (otherwise you would have row duplication, which is prohibited in the *Relational Model*).

> *A Member, however, inherits its values from the Group that it belongs to*

That implies that each Member belongs to just one Group.

- If Members can belong to more than one Group, we have to (a) specify which Group he receives default attributes from, and (b) change the model.  It is easy.
- If you would like the Predicates, please ask.

> *What is the best way to design this in a database?*

That of course, leads to the next, and obvious, question: *What is the best way to design the objects to use the database?*

- If I were in your position, I would use a View each, gather all the data for Group, and for Member, and then use that to load your objects. If you need the code for that, just ask.
- Keep the objects simple, you do not need to mess around with trying to implement "inheritance" in the objects.  That is, keep the data issues in the database, and the object issues in the objects, and do not scramble your eggs.  We build software components for deployment, not pre-1970 style monolithic object layers.
- And of course, use ACID Transactions to update the database, not OO or ORM "persistence".
- It is 2015, after all, and we have had the *Relational Model* since 1970; SQL platforms including ACID since 1984.  There is no need to regress to ancient filing systems.  I give this warning because I am quite aware that the OO/ORM crowd advise the implementation of pre-relational filing systems.

Please feel free to ask questions or comment.

Comment: my apologies for not yet reacting on your answer, except for voting up. This is due to not fully understanding your the concepts you have suggested. I need more "acid" to digest it :).

Comment: @mnish.  If you ask a specific question (here in the comments) re the concept you do not understand, I can answer, and we can progress.  The [**Open Architecture**](http://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Article/Application%20Architecture/Open%20Architecture.pdf) Standards might help you.  If your question is *What is an ACID Transaction ?*, please open a new Question, and ping me.  Digestion is important, take your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to have attr1 and attr2 fields in Member table contain NULL initially. And you will be able to check if attr1 or attr2 is NULL than you need to query Group table
If attr1 and attr2 contain some values that means those field(s) were overwritten.

Comment: This will work if null means that the value has to be fetched from the group. What if the member attribute was set to null deliberately? This means that null has different meanings. Also there are a lot of attributes, so I have to check on null for every attribute which will pollute my code.

Comment: If attributes can be inherited independently, i.e. attr1 inherited from group but attr2 - not inherited, I think you have no choice and need to check every attribute. If inheritance all or none, probably you can add additional field to indicate is attributes inherited or not.